# ¿Se encuentra de forma correcta el código python?

Tags: python

He realizado este código Python para hacer la traducción del flujo pero tengo dudas en los if que presentan un asterisco ya que no se si se estan ejecutando de forma correcta.

```
cad=input('Entra la cadena de caracters')
j=len(cad)
i=j-1

if(cad[i]<=cad[j]):
    c=cad[i]
    cad[i]=cad[j]
    cad[i]=c
    i=i+1
    *if(i==0):
        j=j+1
        *if(j==1):
            print(cad)
else:
    i=i+1
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Perdón por la calidad del flujo, lo he replicado de forma rápida en word para que se entendiera de forma correcta. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Cual es el problema con este codigo? funciono? en este sitio no se revisa codigo, se resuelven problemas....

Comment: El código no podría ejecutarse debido a que en lugares como `cad[i] = cad[j]` estás intentando cambiar el valor de un elemento de `cad` y eso no puede hacerse por que en Python **las cadenas son inmutables**. Al margen de eso, el diagrama de flujo parece contener un error ya que la secuencia de instrucciones `c=cad[i]; cad[i]=cad[j];cad[i]=c` acaba dejando `cad[i]` igual que estaba al principio, cuando sospecho que lo que se buscaba era intercambiar `cad[i]` con `cad[j]`. Finalmente tu código no sería una implementación correcta del diagrama, pues faltan los bucles.

Comment: Deberías aprender un poco más sobre la forma en la que debes hacer las preguntas, para que toda persona que lea tu pregunta sepa la duda concreta que tengas y pueda entenderla rápidamente y ayudarte. Además la forma en la que escribes código, si bien es correcta, podrías mejorarla haciendo un código bien diseñado y con un buen estilo, sería incluso más eficiente para vos mismo, y para los que lean el código al momento de responder las preguntas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el diagrama tanto `Elegir(cad)` como `Escribir(cad)` son funciones que deberían ser implementadas como en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
def Elegir():
    """ Invita al usuario a elegir una cadena de caracteres """
    
    # Variables que mueren al terminar la funcion
    cad=input('Entra la cadena de caracteres: ')
    j=len(cad)
    i=j-1

    return cad, j, i


# Ejecuta la funcion e inicia las variables
cad, j, i = Elegir()

# Test: Control Valores
print(cad)
print(j)
print(i)
```

---

Ahora bien...

```
i=i+1
if(i==0):
```

A menos que no esperes un valor -1 ese `if` nunca se ejecutará. Porque agarras un número le sumas 1 y luego le dices si es igual a 0 haz tal cosa. A ese punto se comprendía mejor `if(i==-1):`

Si necesitabas incrementar el valor de i lo hacías al interno del `if`, además veo que tanto en el `if` como en el `else` incrementas el valor de i y que en el `else` no haces otra cosa. A ese punto podrías prescindir del `else` de esta manera:

```
if(cad[i]<=cad[j]):
    ... # código que no incrementa el valor de i

# incrementa valor de i siempre
i=i+1
```

Comment: Perdona, no vi el comentario que me pusiste aquí, muchas gracias por resolver mi duda

Comment: He llegado a esta conclusión y he substituido los if, diría que ahora se encuentra de forma más o menos correcta

Comment: Creo entender tu explicación pero lo que se me pide que haga en trascribir lo del diagrama a python y esta parte la entiendo tal que asi y no veo el fallo c=cad[i]
cad[i]=cad[j]
cad[i]=c

Comment: En realidad no me había percatado que tu profesor te pedía hacer justo eso en su diagrama. Es cierto que es un código absurdo pero tratándose de un ejercicio orientado a las condiciones comprendo el motivo.

Comment: La segunda orientación del diagrama creo que dice Elegir(cad), Si el profesor la escribió con los paréntesis, ¿me parece que se espera que hagas una función?

Comment: Diría que si, por lo que he entendido espera que haga una función pero no acabo de enteder como plasmarlo en código python por que diría que el diagrama en sí, no es correcto

Comment: Amplié mi respuesta para mostrarte como implementar las funciones